# What is the cohomology of higher tensor powers of the dualizing sheaf of a smooth projective curve?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective curve over an alg. closed field $k$. Let $\omega_X := \Omega^1_X$ be its dualizing sheaf.

Is $H^1(X,\omega_X^{\otimes m}) = 0$ for $m > 1$?

How does one see this?

Answer (score 2):

This is only true if the genus $g$ of the curve is $\ge 2$.

By Serre duality,
$$h^1(\omega_X^{\otimes m}) = h^0(\omega_X^{\otimes (1-m)})$$
Since $\omega_X$ has degree $2g-2$, $\deg\omega_X^{\otimes (1-m)} = (1-m)(2g-2)$, and thus if $g\ge 2$, then this degree is negative when $m\ge 2$, so by Riemann-Roch $h^0 = 0$ in this case.

However, if $g = 0$, then $\deg\omega_X^{\otimes(1-m)} = -2(1-m)$, then again by Riemann-Roch, if $m\ge 2$, we find that
$$h^0(\omega_X^{\otimes(1-m)}) = -2(1-m) + 1 = 2m-1\ne 0$$
Similarly, if $g = 1$, then $\deg\omega_X^{\otimes(1-m)} = 0$ - in fact $\omega_X = \mathcal{O}_X$, and so for trivial reasons $h^0(\omega_X^{\otimes(1-m)}) = h^0(\mathcal{O}_X) = 1$.

Comment: What is $h^1(...)$?

Comment: @rtz $h^i(\cdots) = \text{dim}_k H^i(\cdots)$